# Rational Bézier Curves are projectively invariant

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, curves, projective-geometry, bezier-curve

I want to prove that a Rational Bézier Curve is not only affine invariant but also a projective invariant. By affine invariance i mean that applying an affine map to the curve is the same as applying it to it's control points and then building the curve from their images. When books like CAGED and NURBS talk about projective invariance i find them not so formal.
What do they mean by projective map? For me a projective map is a map between projective spaces induced to quotients by a linear injective map between vector spaces. Meanwhile a Rational Bézier Curve lives in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Edit:
Should i consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a subset of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ with the map that sends $(x,y,z) \to [x,y,z,1]$? Applying a projective map to a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ means applying it to $[x,y,z,1]$ and then projecting it dividing by the forth homogeneous coordinate?
How can i apply a projective map (between projective spaces) to something living in a vector space...

Comment: Yes to the last sentence with an interrogation mark ; you should/must use this correspondence, taking into account the fact that, if there is a denominator it is common to all terms. For example  $\left( x=\tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},y=\tfrac{2t}{1+t^2},z=\tfrac{1}{1+t^2} \right) \to [1-t^2, 2t, 1, 1+t^2]$ and then work with linear transformation in $\mathbb{R^4}$ which amounts to projective transformations in  $\mathbb{R^3}.$

Comment: Okay but how can i formalize the idea of a projective transformation of, for example,  $\mathbb{R}^3$ if it is usually a map between projective spaces? Where can i find a definition of the procedure in my edit without being ambiguous?

Comment: I do not understand your last question. I see you have well understood that once you have applied a $4 \times 4$ matrix to your $4 \times 1$ vector, for example $[1-t^2, 2t,1,1+t^2]^T$ (where $T=$ transposition), you do the inverse operation  $[X,Y,Z,T] \to (X/T,Y/T,Z/T]$.

Comment: In order to prove that a Rational Bézier Curve (which lives in $\mathbb{R}^3$) is projective invariant i need to know precisely what a projective map is. I know that such a map is between prjective spaces and it is not a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) so i don't really get what i have to prove (while for affine invariance everything is clear since an affine map is a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$). So i thought that in this context there is a definition for projective map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and it is defined as in my edit.

Comment: But this bothers me because if that is the case which is the real definition of projective map?

Comment: There is no more to understand than the fundamental **commutative diagram** p. 13 of this interesting [document](https://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/0512/0512125.pdf) (often physicists have a complementary perspective...)