# Projective transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projective-geometry

I am studying computer aided geometry and I have a background in mathematics.
For me a (real) projective transformation is a map $f: \mathbb{RP}^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n  $ induced by a linear isomorphism $F: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ since being injective it maps lines to lines (m-subspaces to m-subspaces).
In the context of graphic design they usually never propey define projective maps, they usually project something onto a plane or use the following construction:

Given $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we consider the point $(x, y, z,1) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ (i.e. a copy of $\mathbb{R}^3$ on the affine hyperplane $\{w=1\}$, then we apply a bijective linear map on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and project the image back on the hyperplane (which causes some trouble if the image has forth coordinate equal to zero).
This process on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called a projective map. What is the link with my definition? I am sure it might involve considering homogeneous coordinates $(x, y, z) \to [x : y : z : 1]$, anyhow I don't get why the confused notation, they seem different things.

Comment: Please, mention your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4428529/305862 asked yesterday to which I had attempted to answer. Honestly, I find it difficult to understand exactly what is your question : is it in fact about an  **"intrinsic (coordinate free) definition"** of projective space, somewhat independent of homogeneous coordinates ? ... and therefore a coordinates-free definition of projective transformations. Btw: the "commutative diagram" I advised you to look at is the top of the iceberg of a "categorical-approach" of projective spaces and their morphisms.

Comment: I took a look at the diagram where a bijective linear map corresponds to an equivalence class of linear maps in a projective functor fashion. (I think) I understood that. What really bothers me is that $[C] $ is what we call projective map, while in my study I find the idea of projective map, for example, from $/mathbb{R}^3 $ to itself. Using the diagram I can relate an element $C \in GL(3,/mathbb{R})$ with an element in $[C] \in GL(3,/mathbb{R})$ while I still don't understand how the procedure $(x, y, z)^t \to (x, y, z, 1)^t \to A(x, y, z, 1)^t$ ecc... Is called and how it works

Answer (score 1):

The $1$ is an artifact of homogenous coordinates and makes sure that your vectors are normalized with respect to that coordinate. The $1$ should never be zero, or anything else for that matter. This is because the augmented matrix form of an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) takes advantage of this for computational reasons and should be normalized at every step to ensure that the $1$ is always there. The OpenGL transformation object is a $4 \times 4$ matrix for this reason. Even if you're not working in OpenGL directly your API probably has this transform object implemented.

One advantage is that you can now do vector addition with matrix multiplication allowing you to encode the matrix and the vector it acts on within the same matrix. Another advantage is for the [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) which requires homogenous coordinates to do correctly. It's actually the perspective projection that motivated the study of projective spaces, and gave them their name. You can vaguely see how vanishing points have something to do with lines through the origin but you can make this idea more precise by studying the [viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).

Finally the OpenGL transform allows you to encode transformation and positional data in a single matrix. This is really useful when drawing objects relative to some other object, such as an arm with two joints. You want each joint to act independently but stay connected so one part will need position and transform information about the other to draw correctly. The affine transform matrix representing where each part of the arm is in relation to the joints will simply reduce to this matrix multiplication.

Comment: IMHO, the question is more about theoretical foundations...

Comment: @JeanMarie The algebraic definition can be derived directly by computing the viewing frustum. As I mentioned, the theory is actually motivated by the study of the perspective projection and we choose the algebraic definition for convenience since it gives us a purely mathematical means of describing it without appealing to human vision but it's impossible to miss the connection when you start with the vision problem and work towards the algebra.